# PHP- get html element value

Tags: php, html

Hi
In jQuery, we can use the script below to get html element value:

```
<p id="some">test</p>

$(function() {
    $a = $('#some').text();
});
```

In PHP, how can we do the same function?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use phpQuery http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 1):

Or Use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/